# Finding a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the linear transformation $T: \mathbb {R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2} $ such as $T(e_1 + e_2)=  \displaystyle\binom{2}{4}$ and $T(e_1 - e_2)=  \displaystyle\binom{-2}{4}$ then the linear transformation applied to the vector $\displaystyle\binom{x}{y} $ is

$a)$ $\displaystyle\binom{2x}{4y}$

$b)$ $\displaystyle\binom{4y}{2x}$

$c)$ $\displaystyle\binom{2y}{4x}$

$d)$ $\displaystyle\binom{2y}{0}$

I've actually thought through this way too much but I'm still not sure about how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Solve for $T(e_1)$ and $T(e_2)$ using linearity. Then what is $T(xe_1+ye_2)$?